# how to give to user alert in case user type reboot/init 6 command

Tags: rhel, reboot

We have very sensitive Hadoop cluster with 3 nodes

We want to avoid reboot of the linux redhat 7.5 machines by users , 
So I was thinking about the following

Each time user decided to type

```
reboot
```

Or

```
init 6
```

or

```
shoutdown -r now
```

then , he will get the following warning?

```
Reboot this machine isn’t recommended in case application not stopped or service are not down
```

So how we can give to user alert in case he type reboot/init 6 command ?

Comment: Why/how would an unprivileged user be able to reboot the system? Do all users have full access to root through `sudo`?

Comment: yes all user have access to do reboot

Comment: Could you consider being a bit more restrictive with what commands the users have root access to, possibly by more carefully formulating the `sudoers` file?

Comment: user can do anything full access , what we want is only to give them alert when doing reboot that all

Comment: The fact that you even need to ask this question indicates that you probably haven't set up the system startup/shutdown scripts and/or `systemd` service files (in RHEL 7.x you can use either) to make sure your application/service will automatically shut down in a controlled fashion as part of a system shutdown. I would recommend you to do that first. All the commands you mentioned will execute a controlled system shutdown. If the user has already decided that the system **needs** to be rebooted, a warning is unlikely to change their mind; they probably think the application is failing.

Comment: this isnt only services , for example I used hadoop dashboard that contain many services tis are not linux services , so in case someone reboot the machine without to stop hadoop services then this is very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Debian-based system, then you could install the `molly-guard` package. This replaces the "dangerous" commands with a wrapper that asks you to confirm the action by entering the hostname of the system.

An alternative could be to use shell aliases, although that won't help against the `sudo reboot` variant.

The above are described in more detail on [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/how-to-protects-linux-and-unix-machines-from-accidental-shutdownsreboots-with-molly-guard/)

Comment: as you know we have redhta 7.5 ( RHEL ) , so maybe you can suggest something like molly-guard for redhat?

Comment: As I said, use shell aliases; details are on the page I linked to. I don't know of any alternative on RHEL that works like molly-guard.

Comment: aliases isn't the solution , must be other elegant solution